# How to follow tcp streams continuously along the capture with tshark / wireshark?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I display the TCP stream of an already finished capture written in `out.pcap` with

```
END=$(tshark -r out.pcap -T fields -e tcp.stream | sort -n | tail -1); 
for ((i=0;i<=END;i++));
do 
echo $i; tshark -r out.pcap -qz follow,tcp,ascii,$i 
done
```

**How can I display newly terminated TCP streams in this fashion along the packet capture?**

Comment: You are looking for a UNIX shell solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggest to use `tcpflow` instead.

If tshark should really be used, an ugly solution would be

```
REFF=/tmp/.streams
echo "" > $REFF
while true 
do
tshark -r $@ -T fields -e tcp.stream 2> /dev/null | sort -nu | sed '/^$/d' | while read i
do
    if [ -z "$(cat $REFF | grep "^$i$" )" ]
    then
          tshark -r $@ -qz follow,tcp,ascii,$i  | tee ${@}-stream-$i.txt
          echo $i >> $REFF
    fi
done
done
```

Comment: Could you give an example of the `tcpflow` command usage? (I have not used it before.)

Comment: I think I figured it out...to print text of TCP connections on port 9000 use `sudo tcpflow -i any -c port 9000`