# Is it possible to regenerate a TCP request with the help of tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

I'm developing a backend server and here is how the architecture of the backend looks like:

```
APP --> Server1 --> Server2 --> Server3 --> MyServer
```

APP sends a HTTP request to the `Server1`, and all of the servers at backend communicate each other with the method RPC, which is based on the TCP protocol.

I'm developing the `MyServer` and since my job hasn't finished yet, I need to do many tests, but the `Server3` is not always available.

I don't know what `Server1`, `Server2` and `Server3` did and the RPC from `Server3` to `MyServer` is really complicated, it contains many parameters that I don't know. What I need is to capture a request from `Server3`, copy it's content to a script so that I can run the script to simulate a request.

Let me make an example:

`Server3` will send a RCP to `MyServer` with the parameters `p1`, `p2`, `p3`. For me, I only care about `p3`, so I process the `p3`, generate a new parameter `p4`, and send `p1`, `p2` and `p4` to another server. So I need to simulate a RPC from `Server3` so that I can send whenever I need to test the `MyServer`.

**About protocol**

Our team used a private framework, it has its own protocol to make a RPC. All I know is that the protocol is based on TCP, instead of HTTP. So what I need is to capture a request from `Server3` and replay it whenever I need.

Comment: hm, are these requests stateless? What kind of protocol are these servers speaking? Just some REST?

Comment: @MarcusMüller  It's not HTTP protocol. I re-edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with HTTP, a much better tool instead of `tcpdump` is a "transparent proxy". This can then also re-run requests.

There are quite a few transparent proxies around, google.

One example is `mitmproxy`, and here is how to [replay requests](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/mitmproxytutorial-replayrequests/).

Comment: Thanks man, nice one but I'm not dealing with HTTP. I just re-edited my question. But your answer just reminds me to try to find some TCP replay technique.

Comment: Then have a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332645/how-to-follow-tcp-streams-continuously-along-the-capture-with-tshark-wireshark) Q&A.